# JavaScript: Get the color object in a array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to get only the color values from the array and set the necessary css class.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.kalendar').kalendar({
        events: [
            {
                title:"National Holiday",
                start: {
                    date: 20140815,
                    time: "12.00"
                },
                end: {
                    date: "20140815",
                    time: "12.00"
                },
                color: "red"
            },
            {
                title:"State Holiday",
                start: {
                    date: 20140818,
                    time: "12.00"
                },
                end: {
                    date: "20140818",
                    time: "12.00"
                },
                color: "blue"
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

now when i try this code, they all end up having a blue color. what am i doing wrong here?

```
for (var j = 0; j < this.options.events.length; j++) {
    var thiscolor = this.options.events[j];
    if (thiscolor.color == 'red') {
        $day.addClass('red-events');
    } else if (thiscolor.color == 'blue') { 
        $day.addClass('blue-events');
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you are iterating over all elements in `this.oprions.events` and since the last element has `color: "blue"`, `else if (thiscolor.color == 'blue')` will be true eventually and all elements in `$day` get that class assigned. Basically, the whole `for` loop is equivalent to `$day.addClass('red-events blue-events');`. Since you haven't explained what you are trying to achieve, what `$day` is and since you haven't provided a complete example, we can't really suggest a solution.

Comment: @FelixKling, `$day` is `$day = $('<div class="c-day"></div>');` what i'm trying to do is compare the color string in the loop and, if it matches, set necessary css class for a particular event.

Comment: But why the loop? You already know that the first element has the color red and the second one has the color blue. Both elements will match at some point. In the first iteration, `thiscolor.color == 'red'` is true, in the second iteration, `thiscolor.color == 'blue'` is true. I don't understand what you are trying to match here.

Comment: @FelixKling, because there are going to be lots of holidays in the events. I'm pasting here only two items for example.

Comment: Well, I already explained why you get what you get. I don't know a solution since I don't know what the desired outcome is.

Comment: Isn't this all what you need `for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    console.log(events[i].color);
}`